# MDX calculated measure on dimension value without measure value

Tags: mdx, measure

I am new to mdx and SSAS, We are trying to convert our store procedure to mdx query. I have a cube like below:

Fact table：

```
         [Target] (FK),
         [Date] (FK),
         [Action] (FK),
         [Amount] (Measure),
```

Dim Date:

```
        [DateKey] (pk),
        [Date],
        [DayOfYear],
        [DayofWeek],
        [....]
```

Dim Action:  has fourkind of actions (added, removed, connected, ..)

```
        [ID] (PK)
        [Name]
```

Dim Target:

```
        [ID] (PK)
        [Name]
```

I want to create a calculated measure like what we did in t-sql

```
 SELECT ....,
 SUM(

   CASE 
         WHEN a.[Action]='added' 

         THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, a.[Date],GETUTCDATE()) 
         ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, a.[Date],GETUTCDATE())*-1
         END

)/NULLIF( SUM(CASE WHEN a.[Action]='added' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0)
 AS 'AverageLifespan'
 FROM FilterData a 
 GROUP BY a.[Target]
```

I have tried following but failed, it only returns 0 ;

```
With Member [Measures].[LifeSpan] as
CASE  
WHEN  [Dim  Action Types].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Dim  Action Types].[Name].&[added] THEN  1*'datediff("d",[Dim Date].[Date],Now()) '
WHEN [Dim  Action Types].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim  Action Types].[Name].&[removed] THEN -1*'datediff("d",[Dim Date].[Date],Now()) '
ELSE  0
End 
select [Measures].[LifeSpan] on columns,
[Dim Action Targets].[Name].Children on rows
from [OLAP Prep]
```

-----------output---------------

```
                         LifeSpan

tilerecipes/account-news    0
tilerecipes/competitornews  0
tilerecipes/innovation-blog 0
tilerecipes/sales-now       0
tilerecipes/inbox           0
tilerecipes/in-the-news     0
tilerecipes/jobs            0
tilerecipes/l-and-d         0
```

Tried on below query, still not working  (removed the date part, just for testing):

```
 With Member [Measures].[LifeSpan] as
 CASE  
 WHEN [Dim  Action Types].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Dim  Action Types].                [Name].&[added] THEN  1 
 WHEN [Dim  Action Types].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim  Action Types].  [Name].&[removed] THEN -1
 WHEN [Dim  Action Types].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim  Action Types].[Name].[All] THEN Sum([Dim  Action Types].[Name].Children,[Measures].[LifeSpan])   -- this will work.
 ELSE  0
 End

 select [Measures].[LifeSpan] on columns,
 [Dim  Action Types].[Name].Members on rows
 from [OLAP Prep]

  --------Output------------

                  LifeSpan
 All                   0
added                  1
connected              0
disconnected           0
removed               -1
```

Comment: Finally fixed it by adding a named calculation column in dsv, then use that column as measure

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing to remember in MDX : **Calculated measures are not aggregated.**

When you develop along the `[Dim Action Targets].[Name]` Axis, the `[Dim Action Targets].[Name]` default member is used, which is by default  `[Dim Action Targets].[Name].[All]`

If you tried

```
select [Measures].[LifeSpan] on columns,
[Dim Action Types].[Name].Members on rows
from [OLAP Prep]
```

You will see your calculated measures behave properly, except for the  `[Dim  Action Types].[Name].[All]` Member.

In order for your calculated measure to behave properly on your original request

```
With Member [Measures].[LifeSpan] as
CASE  
WHEN [Dim  Action Types].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Dim  Action Types].[Name].&[added] THEN  1*'datediff("d",[Dim Date].[Date],Now()) '
WHEN [Dim  Action Types].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim  Action Types].[Name].&[removed] THEN -1*'datediff("d",[Dim Date].[Date],Now()) '
WHEN [Dim  Action Types].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim  Action Types].[Name].[All] THEN Sum([Dim  Action Types].[Name].Children,[Measures].[LifeSpan]) -- this will work.
ELSE  0
End
```

---

Well, the simplest way would be to create a LifeSpan measure in your cube definition,  make it point to your Amount column of your fact table.  Let the default behaviour

Now, go to the Calculation tab of the cube definition. Switch to Script mode.

You should see the "CALCULATE" instruction.

```
CALCULATE;

Scope([Measures].[LifeSpan]);
    This = 0; // We zero out the whole thing first
    Scope([Dim Date].[Date].Children,[Dim  Action Types].[Name].&[added]})
        This =  datediff("d",[Dim Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER,Now())
    End Scope;
    Scope([Dim Date].[Date].Children,[Dim  Action Types].[Name].&[removed]})
        This =  -datediff("d",[Dim Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER,Now())
    End Scope;
End Scope;
```

This measure will aggregate the right way.

Comment: thank you for your reply. tried it on my cube, but it is still not working, please check my question, edit just few minutes ago.

Comment: thank you again. Finally fix it by adding a named calculation column in dsv, then use that column as measure. By following your code, I learned a lot about "Scope" and "Calculated Members". Thank you!

Comment: sorry it is still remain unfixed.  I tried created a named calculated column for it where I used the GETDATE() as today to calculate it,  I thought the GETDATE() should be the date time when query is running, but I tested today it is not! It the date the cube is deployed.  It’s frustrating !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'MemberValue' like this :

```
WHEN 
[Dim  Action Types].[Name].MemberValue IS 
[Dim  Action Types].[Name].&[added] 
THEN 
1*'datediff("d",[Dim Date].[Date],Now())
```